# is it possible to compile x264 for webassembly using emscripten?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, x264, libx264

I am trying to build x264 code for webassembly.
i use emconfigure to configure. like below

```
emconfigure ./configure --prefix="$(pwd)/em" --enable-shared --enable-static  --disable-cli  --disable-gpl
```

But this was throwing "No working C compiler found." error. i have gcc compiler 9.3.0 version and have tried reinstalling build-essentials and gcc but still same issue.

config.log also doesn't help.

If i provide --host cross compiler flag then it is generating libx264.so file, but i am not sure whether this is right as the wasm code should work in every browser in (windows/mac/linux)

please tell me first whether compiling x264 using emscripten is possible?
If yes, please tell me what is the correct steps to do it

Comment: When you pass `--host` for cross-compiling, you should specify wasm32 as a target, not Windows / Mac / Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build it with following flags:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=(
  --host=i686-gnu                     # use i686 linux
  --enable-static                     # enable building static library
  --disable-cli                       # disable cli tools
  --disable-asm                       # disable asm optimization
  --extra-cflags="-s USE_PTHREADS=1"  # pass this flags for using pthreads
)
emconfigure ./configure "${ARGS[@]}"
emmake make -j4
```